# Changing a memory process with windbg?

Tags: debugging, architecture, process, binary, windbg

I would like to know if it is possible to inject a binary inside a memory process with windbg? Hooking windbg on the process to potentially replace the instructions of the original binary or add the other binary instructions to be run by the process? (as well as injecting the dlls?) Would it be possible to script this?

Basically I would like to know how much can be done with windbg to a process and how much of the process could be modified. (Could I technically use windbg to map a whole binary and its dlls into an existing process?)

Answer (score 1):

With windbg to hook on process, you can modify almost all memory owned by that process, for example, the instruction, stack, heap memory etc.

Comment: You can indeed alloc memory. From debugger.chm: The .dvalloc command calls VirtualAllocEx to allocate new memory for the target process. The allocated memory permits reading, writing, and execution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that but in theory it is possible (at least some of what you've asked for).

You can store current instructions, rewrite them with a call to `LoadLibrary` and store your DLL name in the stack. After your DLL is loaded you need to restore rewritten instructions and execute them (or you can emulate them in windbg by doing manually what those instructions do).

Also you can write extensions to windbg to do complex stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't even need WinDbg for this. You can do something along the lines of:

- Call `OpenProcess` to get a handle to the target process
- Allocate some memory in the target process using `VirtualAlloc`
- Write the code into the memory `WriteProcessMemory`
- Call `CreateRemoteThread` to execute the code